# database collation differences

Tags: collation

I have a database for a site I am developing in WAMP. The collation for the *database* is `latin1_swedish_ci` but every *table* in the database is `utf84mb_unicode_ci`.

Should I be worried about this?

In the future I can use `utf84mb_unicode_ci` for both, but what about the databases I already have content in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From quick check of the MySQL manual the *database* collation is only relevant for database–level operations (emphasis mine):

> - **For CREATE TABLE statements**, the database character set and collation
>     are used as default values for table definitions if the table
>     character set and collation are not specified. To override this,
>     provide explicit CHARACTER SET and COLLATE table options.
> - **For LOAD DATA statements** that include no CHARACTER SET clause, the
>     server uses the character set indicated by the character_set_database
>     system variable to interpret the information in the file. To override
>     this, provide an explicit CHARACTER SET clause.
> - **For stored routines** (procedures and functions), the database character
>     set and collation in effect at routine creation time are used as the
>     character set and collation of character data parameters for which the
>     declaration includes no CHARACTER SET or COLLATE attribute. To
>     override this, provide explicit CHARACTER SET and COLLATE attributes.
>
> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-database.html

For WordPress it is *table* level collation that matters. That's why it actually *can* do things like creating/upgrading `utf8mb4` tables inside a database that isn't.

So this seems to be non–issue and you could probably even set collation on existing *databases* without any trouble (not the same story at all with *tables* however!).